# SQL update all negative numbers to null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a table in SQL Server with around of 300 columns. I want to create a stored procedure that replaces all the negative numbers with `null`.

The table has columns of type `float`, `integer`, `nvarchar` and so on.

I try to do it with T-SQL, but can't. Please could help me?.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I need a stored procedure that transforms all numeric columns to null if they are negative. The table is dynamic and may be increasing or decreasing the number of columns.

Comment: What does it mean for a `varchar()` field to be negative?

Comment: Update table set someColumn = null where someColumn < 0 will do floats and ints. VarChar? where SomeBadlyTypedColumn like '-%' maybe??? Otherwise a bit more detail...

Comment: Only need float and integer negatives to null. i've varchar columns but these do not have to change.

Comment: C.J. Date, normalization, first normal form. Just some research suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     DECLARE @updateStatement AS VARCHAR(MAX)
     SET  @updateStatement = null

      set @target_table =''
      select * from systypes
          select @updateStatement = COALESCE(@updateStatement+'UPDATE '+  @TARGET_TABLE+' SET  '+c.name+ '= NULL WHERE' + c.name +' >0;' ,'UPDATE '+  @TARGET_TABLE +' SET  '+c.name+ '= NULL WHERE' + c.name +' >0;'  ) from syscolumns as c
      inner join sysobjects as o on c.id= o.id 
      INNER JOIN systypes as t on c.xtype = t.xtype
      where o.name= @TARGET_TABLE
      AND T.name in('int','real','money','decimal')

      select @updateStatement
--EXEC (@updateStatement)
```

You will need to add more to the where clause for `T.name in ()` to hit all the data types you want. But this will query all the columns in 1 table `@Target_Table` then create update statements for each column in that table, if they are negative it will set the ALL ROWS for that column to null.

To make work uncomment out the `EXEC(@UpdateStatement)` THIS IS A REAL TERRIBLE IDEA, if you are dead set on doing this review your update statements

---

*AND TAKE A BACKUP UP FIRST*

EDIT*** **THIS WILL NOT TAKE INTO ACCOUNT WEIRD FLOATING POINT MATH**

Comment: I do some changes to make it work. Add Begin - End. Add float in t.Name in. Add and space after where clause. Thanks !!!